# Java ExecutorService threads with functions that don't support threading

Tags: java, multithreading, opencv, image-processing, executorservice

I am trying to leverage multi-threading for quite a heavy image processing program. The multi-threading is mostly working great and decreasing my runtime x4. However, some external libraries that I am using are not very stable when being executed by multiple thread and I occasionally get errors which reflect that (for example, an empty image error when in fact no images are empty etc.)

I have identified two such functions that belong to an external library (opencv) and I would like to isolate those if possible, so that when a thread hit that function, it always waits for the previous thread to finish - this way the problematic functions will never be executed more than once at a given time.

Can this be achieved in Java? How?

Thanks

UPDATE : `synchronized` Java function does not work. Occasionally (it is hard to reproduce which is why it is so frustrating) I would see an opencv error coming from a function that works fine 99.9% of the runs.

An example of an error I just recently got, and related to the opencv `fillPoly`function:

```
ERROR main.java.com.ibm.staple.Staple  - cv  Exception:  OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\drawing.cpp :2403 error: (-215:Assertion failed) p.checkVector(2, CV_32S) >= 0 in function ‘cv::fillPoly’
```

Comment: Are these functions smaller parts of a larger pipeline that can be mostly parallel except for certain "small roads", or are they pieces that are dispatched distinctly?

Comment: They are smaller part of a larger pipeline/workflow of image processing and manipulation

Answer (score -2):

You can easily acheive this using Synchronization in Java. Synchronization will make the method accessible to only one thread at a time. You can find lots of article in google about Synchronization.

Ex :

```
    synchronized void yourMethodname(int x){//synchronized method  

// Your code block inside.

}
```